# Prove that $q\equiv (q\mod 2^n)+\lfloor\frac{q}{2^n}\rfloor(\mod 2^n-1)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Prove that $q\equiv (q\mod 2^n)+\lfloor\frac{q}{2^n}\rfloor(\mod 2^n-1)$.

This expression is given in [Lucas-Lehmer Primality Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Lehmer_primality_test). I am wondering if there is a proof of this, as it is not listed on the page. Thank You.

Comment: Hint: Using euclidean division: $q=k*2^n+a=a+k+k*(2^n-1)$, now do the computation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a$ and $q$ be positive integers. Then we can write $q$ in terms of $a$ as
$$q = \alpha a + \beta,$$
where integers $\alpha \ge 0$ and $0 \le \beta < a$ are the quotient and remainder after division when $q$ is divided by $a$. Observe that
$$q \equiv \beta \mod{a},$$
and $$\left\lfloor \frac{q}{a}\right\rfloor = \left\lfloor \alpha + \frac{\beta}{a}\right\rfloor = \alpha.$$
Therefore,
$$q = a\cdot \left\lfloor \frac{q}{a}\right\rfloor + (q \mod{a}) = (a-1)\cdot \left\lfloor \frac{q}{a}\right\rfloor +\left\lfloor \frac{q}{a}\right\rfloor+ (q \mod{a}).$$
Consequently,
$$q \equiv (q \mod{a}) + \left\lfloor \frac{q}{a}\right\rfloor \mod{a-1}.$$
In your case, $a = 2^n$.